# no actionMethods param for JsonP in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

i want to fire a `POST`  `jsonp` request to the server but the issue is 
in `Ext.data.proxy.JsonP`there is no paramenter `actionMethods` with which i can set `read: 'POST'` so that to get the data from server i can fire up a `POST` request.

so is there a way to set `POST` for `read` but for `jsonp`

here is my code ,

```
Ext.define('demo.store.ProfileStore',{

    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:[
                'demo.model.ProfileModel',
                'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'
    ],

    config: {
        model: 'demo.model.ProfileModel',

        proxy:{

            type:'jsonp',
            url:'http://www.example.com/file/gd.php',
            actionMethods:{

                read: 'POST',

            },
            reader:{

                type:'json',
                totalProperty:'count',
                rootProperty:'rows'
            },
            extraParams:{

                search:'false'
            }



        }
    }
});
```

Comment: JSONP adds a script tag to the page, it will necessarily trigger a GET request. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17926455/1387519) answered yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do a post. The way JSONP works is by inserting a script tag into the document which then makes a call to the remote server. Because of this, the only method available when using it is `GET`.